# Poisson cumulative distribution in GAMS

Tags: gams-math

Can anyone help me with this? I defined a Parameter N and then defined the chance of N being less than M(a variable), but it's not working, could you please take a look at this?

```
*Number of emergency patients arriving at time period t on day d
 Parameter N(t,d);

file emp / '%emp.info%' /;put emp '* problem %gams.i%'/;
$onput
randvar N(t,d) poisson Ltotal
chance (N(t,d)<=M(t,d)) Re(t,d)
$offput
```